# Proposition 3.14: Geometry

Tags: geometry, angle

Please help prove the following proposition: 
 Proposition 3.14
 Supplementary angles of congruent angles are congruent.

Is this right? 
(1) Suppose angle ABC is congruent to angle DEF (given)
(2) We have arbitrary points A, C, and G on the sides of angle ABC, and the supplement angle CBG of angle ABC. We can choose points D, F, and H such that AB≅DE,CB≅FE,and BG≅EH. (C-1)
(3) Triangle ABC is congruent to triangle DEF (C-6)
(4) So AC≅DF and ∡A≅∡D. (def cong triangles)
(5) Also AG≅DH (C-3)
(6) So triangle ACG is congruent to triangle DFH (C-6 SAS)
(7) So CG≅FH and angle G ≅angle H (def cong triangles)
(8) So triangle CBD is cong to triangle FEH (C-6 SAS)
(9) Then angle CBG is congruent to angle FEH (def cong triangles)

Comment: What does make two angles congruent?

Comment: Hint..   If $a + b = c + b$ what can you say about how the numbers $a$ and $c$ are related?  Hint: What is the definition of suplimentary angles?

Comment: That's overly complicated!  Why are you inventing so many unnecessary things.  You have four angles.  You don't need *anything* else. We asked you two *simple* questions.  1) What makes two angles congruent? and 2) What is the *definition* of supplementary?  Answer those.  The prove should be easy.  Almost trivial.

Answer (score 1):

That's overly complicated!  Why are you inventing so many unnecessary things?  You have four angles.  You don't need *anything* else.

Given: $\angle A \cong \angle B$.  $\angle C$ is supplementary to $\angle A$. $\angle D$ is supplementary to $\angle B$.

Pf:  1)$m\angle A = m\angle B$ (def of congruent)

2)$m\angle A + m \angle C = 180$ (def of supplementary)

3)$m\angle D + m \angle B = 180$ (def of supplementary)

The rest is algebra:

> In 3) replace $m \angle B$ with $m\angle A$ to get:
>
>
>  $m\angle D + m \angle A = 180$
>
>
>  Compare $m\angle A + m \angle C = 180$ with $m\angle D + m \angle A = 180$ to get:
>
>
>  $m\angle A + m \angle C=m\angle D + m \angle A$
>
>
>  Subtract $m\angle A$ from both sides to get:
>
>
>    $m\angle C = m\angle D$  and conclude:
>
>
>    $\angle C \cong \angle D$.